# cocoapods show Swift error when installing

Tags: cocoapods, afnetworking, google-places-api, alamofire

I try to 'pod install' my project with some libraries (AFNetworking, GooglePlaces and GoogleMaps). However, it always shows the error:

> [!] Pods written in Swift can only be integrated as frameworks; add
>   `use_frameworks!` to your Podfile or target to opt into using it. The
>   Swift Pods being used are: Alamofire, GooglePlaces, and ObjectMapper

But I only use objective-c frameworks, for Objective C project. I did the research but cannot find how to fix this. My current version of cocoapods is 1.0.0.

Comment: did you find any solution

Answer (score 1):

> The Swift Pods being used are: Alamofire, GooglePlaces, and ObjectMapper

You may be writing in Objective-C but the pods you want to use are not. You would need to add `use_frameworks!` to the Podfile to say that you are fine with making them all frameworks in order to support Swift.